# How to rearrange / restructure array with dates in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, loops, date

I have an array with dates between 10/2017 and 11/2017. The items are listed chronologically.

I'm looking for a PHP-solution to either rearrange the structure of the array or loop intelligently so I can organize the dates as I like.

What I need to echo is something like:
*(old attempt, please ignore this example. Just keeping it here for the already provided solutions. Please see **Update** below.)*

```
'1', '1, 10, 2017', '1, 11, 2017'
'2', '2, 10, 2017', '2, 11, 2017',
...
'30', '30, 10, 2017', '30, 11, 2017',
'31', '31, 10, 2017', ''
```

Note that November (`11`) has only 30 days so there's no 31st entry.

So I need a loop that iterates through the array and echoes all dates with the same starting day and then does a `<br>` or similar. It should always end at the 31st wether there's data or not.

---

**UPDATE:**
I need a slightly different look of my output:

```
['1', '1, 10, 2017', '1, 11, 2017'],
['2', '2, 10, 2017', '2, 11, 2017'],
...
['30', '30, 10, 2017', '30, 11, 2017'],
['31', '31, 10, 2017', '0, 0, 0']
```

Major changes are:

- square brackets
- If there's no value (e.g. 31st of November doesn't exist), I need to output `'0, 0, 0'` and not an empty string as before.

Background is that I have a function which necessarily needs any value, may it be 0.

---

I tried different things (splitting the days, months and years to separate arrays / using for-loops / using foreach-loops) but nothing really worked. My main problem seems to be that each month has a different amount of days.

**Do you have any advices how to get that working?** **May it be better to try to restructure the array or is there any other solution?**

The code should work with different date ranges (not only the ones I mentioned above).

This is my array:

```
    Array
(
    [0] => 1, 10, 2017
    [1] => 2, 10, 2017
    [2] => 3, 10, 2017
    [3] => 4, 10, 2017
    [4] => 5, 10, 2017
    [5] => 6, 10, 2017
    [6] => 7, 10, 2017
    [7] => 8, 10, 2017
    [8] => 9, 10, 2017
    [9] => 10, 10, 2017
    [10] => 11, 10, 2017
    [11] => 12, 10, 2017
    [12] => 13, 10, 2017
    [13] => 14, 10, 2017
    [14] => 15, 10, 2017
    [15] => 16, 10, 2017
    [16] => 17, 10, 2017
    [17] => 18, 10, 2017
    [18] => 19, 10, 2017
    [19] => 20, 10, 2017
    [20] => 21, 10, 2017
    [21] => 22, 10, 2017
    [22] => 23, 10, 2017
    [23] => 24, 10, 2017
    [24] => 25, 10, 2017
    [25] => 26, 10, 2017
    [26] => 27, 10, 2017
    [27] => 28, 10, 2017
    [28] => 29, 10, 2017
    [29] => 30, 10, 2017
    [30] => 31, 10, 2017
    [31] => 1, 11, 2017
    [32] => 2, 11, 2017
    [33] => 3, 11, 2017
    [34] => 4, 11, 2017
    [35] => 5, 11, 2017
    [36] => 6, 11, 2017
    [37] => 7, 11, 2017
    [38] => 8, 11, 2017
    [39] => 9, 11, 2017
    [40] => 10, 11, 2017
    [41] => 11, 11, 2017
    [42] => 12, 11, 2017
    [43] => 13, 11, 2017
    [44] => 14, 11, 2017
    [45] => 15, 11, 2017
    [46] => 16, 11, 2017
    [47] => 17, 11, 2017
    [48] => 18, 11, 2017
    [49] => 19, 11, 2017
    [50] => 20, 11, 2017
    [51] => 21, 11, 2017
    [52] => 22, 11, 2017
    [53] => 23, 11, 2017
    [54] => 24, 11, 2017
    [55] => 25, 11, 2017
    [56] => 26, 11, 2017
    [57] => 27, 11, 2017
    [58] => 28, 11, 2017
    [59] => 29, 11, 2017
    [60] => 30, 11, 2017
)
```

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Why are your dates formatted like that?

Comment: Because I need to use them in my custom function `getOrdersByDay($day_number, $month_number, $year_number)` where day, month and year are used as parameters. Easier for me to have the dates in the array already formatted with comma.

Comment: Handle dates using year first. Get yourself thinking in ISO8601, and if you need a particular output format, deal with that in your formatting when you generate output. Data structures should not be governed by output format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears your desired result is a kind of pseudo-array string.  If you are planning to use this as an array or json, I may be able to refine this code to better suit your ultimate requirements.

Code demonstrating 3 different starting points: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d4bcf5d0716d46e229316d8f0e4aa99a327dc950))

```
function buildPseudoArray($month1,$year1){ // default dates in params: $month1=date('m'),$year1=date('Y') causes Fatal error
    echo "Result for $month1-$year1:\n";
    $m1_last=date('t',strtotime("$year1-$month1"));
    if($month1==12){
        $year2=$year1+1;
        $month2=1;
    }else{
        $year2=$year1;
        $month2=$month1+1;
    }
    $m2_last=date('t',strtotime("$year2-$month2"));
    $result='';
    for($i=1,$stop=31; $i<=$stop; ++$i){
        $result.="['$i', ";
        $result.=$i<=$m1_last ? "'$i, $month1, $year1', " : "'0, 0, 0', ";  // conditionally fill missing dates
        $result.=$i<=$m2_last ? "'$i, $month2, $year2'" : "'0, 0, 0'";  // conditionally fill missing dates
        $result.=']'.($i<$stop ? ',' : '')."\n";  // conditionally add comma to end of row
    }
    return $result;
}

echo buildPseudoArray(1,2017);  // shows 0, 0, 0 in first column
echo "\n---------------------\n";
echo buildPseudoArray('2',2017);  // shows 0, 0, 0 in second column
echo "\n---------------------\n";
echo buildPseudoArray(12,2017);  // shows incrementation into next year
```

Output:

```
Result for 1-2017:
['1', '1, 1, 2017', '1, 2, 2017'],
['2', '2, 1, 2017', '2, 2, 2017'],
['3', '3, 1, 2017', '3, 2, 2017'],
['4', '4, 1, 2017', '4, 2, 2017'],
['5', '5, 1, 2017', '5, 2, 2017'],
['6', '6, 1, 2017', '6, 2, 2017'],
['7', '7, 1, 2017', '7, 2, 2017'],
['8', '8, 1, 2017', '8, 2, 2017'],
['9', '9, 1, 2017', '9, 2, 2017'],
['10', '10, 1, 2017', '10, 2, 2017'],
['11', '11, 1, 2017', '11, 2, 2017'],
['12', '12, 1, 2017', '12, 2, 2017'],
['13', '13, 1, 2017', '13, 2, 2017'],
['14', '14, 1, 2017', '14, 2, 2017'],
['15', '15, 1, 2017', '15, 2, 2017'],
['16', '16, 1, 2017', '16, 2, 2017'],
['17', '17, 1, 2017', '17, 2, 2017'],
['18', '18, 1, 2017', '18, 2, 2017'],
['19', '19, 1, 2017', '19, 2, 2017'],
['20', '20, 1, 2017', '20, 2, 2017'],
['21', '21, 1, 2017', '21, 2, 2017'],
['22', '22, 1, 2017', '22, 2, 2017'],
['23', '23, 1, 2017', '23, 2, 2017'],
['24', '24, 1, 2017', '24, 2, 2017'],
['25', '25, 1, 2017', '25, 2, 2017'],
['26', '26, 1, 2017', '26, 2, 2017'],
['27', '27, 1, 2017', '27, 2, 2017'],
['28', '28, 1, 2017', '28, 2, 2017'],
['29', '29, 1, 2017', '0, 0, 0'],
['30', '30, 1, 2017', '0, 0, 0'],
['31', '31, 1, 2017', '0, 0, 0']

---------------------
Result for 2-2017:
['1', '1, 2, 2017', '1, 3, 2017'],
['2', '2, 2, 2017', '2, 3, 2017'],
['3', '3, 2, 2017', '3, 3, 2017'],
['4', '4, 2, 2017', '4, 3, 2017'],
['5', '5, 2, 2017', '5, 3, 2017'],
['6', '6, 2, 2017', '6, 3, 2017'],
['7', '7, 2, 2017', '7, 3, 2017'],
['8', '8, 2, 2017', '8, 3, 2017'],
['9', '9, 2, 2017', '9, 3, 2017'],
['10', '10, 2, 2017', '10, 3, 2017'],
['11', '11, 2, 2017', '11, 3, 2017'],
['12', '12, 2, 2017', '12, 3, 2017'],
['13', '13, 2, 2017', '13, 3, 2017'],
['14', '14, 2, 2017', '14, 3, 2017'],
['15', '15, 2, 2017', '15, 3, 2017'],
['16', '16, 2, 2017', '16, 3, 2017'],
['17', '17, 2, 2017', '17, 3, 2017'],
['18', '18, 2, 2017', '18, 3, 2017'],
['19', '19, 2, 2017', '19, 3, 2017'],
['20', '20, 2, 2017', '20, 3, 2017'],
['21', '21, 2, 2017', '21, 3, 2017'],
['22', '22, 2, 2017', '22, 3, 2017'],
['23', '23, 2, 2017', '23, 3, 2017'],
['24', '24, 2, 2017', '24, 3, 2017'],
['25', '25, 2, 2017', '25, 3, 2017'],
['26', '26, 2, 2017', '26, 3, 2017'],
['27', '27, 2, 2017', '27, 3, 2017'],
['28', '28, 2, 2017', '28, 3, 2017'],
['29', '0, 0, 0', '29, 3, 2017'],
['30', '0, 0, 0', '30, 3, 2017'],
['31', '0, 0, 0', '31, 3, 2017']

---------------------
Result for 12-2017:
['1', '1, 12, 2017', '1, 1, 2018'],
['2', '2, 12, 2017', '2, 1, 2018'],
['3', '3, 12, 2017', '3, 1, 2018'],
['4', '4, 12, 2017', '4, 1, 2018'],
['5', '5, 12, 2017', '5, 1, 2018'],
['6', '6, 12, 2017', '6, 1, 2018'],
['7', '7, 12, 2017', '7, 1, 2018'],
['8', '8, 12, 2017', '8, 1, 2018'],
['9', '9, 12, 2017', '9, 1, 2018'],
['10', '10, 12, 2017', '10, 1, 2018'],
['11', '11, 12, 2017', '11, 1, 2018'],
['12', '12, 12, 2017', '12, 1, 2018'],
['13', '13, 12, 2017', '13, 1, 2018'],
['14', '14, 12, 2017', '14, 1, 2018'],
['15', '15, 12, 2017', '15, 1, 2018'],
['16', '16, 12, 2017', '16, 1, 2018'],
['17', '17, 12, 2017', '17, 1, 2018'],
['18', '18, 12, 2017', '18, 1, 2018'],
['19', '19, 12, 2017', '19, 1, 2018'],
['20', '20, 12, 2017', '20, 1, 2018'],
['21', '21, 12, 2017', '21, 1, 2018'],
['22', '22, 12, 2017', '22, 1, 2018'],
['23', '23, 12, 2017', '23, 1, 2018'],
['24', '24, 12, 2017', '24, 1, 2018'],
['25', '25, 12, 2017', '25, 1, 2018'],
['26', '26, 12, 2017', '26, 1, 2018'],
['27', '27, 12, 2017', '27, 1, 2018'],
['28', '28, 12, 2017', '28, 1, 2018'],
['29', '29, 12, 2017', '29, 1, 2018'],
['30', '30, 12, 2017', '30, 1, 2018'],
['31', '31, 12, 2017', '31, 1, 2018']
```

---

**This is the prepped code for your Google Charts task:** ([Demo Link](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b2c27a0ee765c1e30cc6c24de193802e07a55805))

```
function getOrdersByDay($i,$m,$y){
    return rand(0,50);  // put your stuff in here
}

function buildPseudoArray($month1,$year1){ // default dates in params: $month1=date('m'),$year1=date('Y') causes Fatal error
    echo "Result for $month1-$year1:\n";
    $m1_last=date('t',strtotime("$year1-$month1"));
    if($month1==12){
        $year2=$year1+1;
        $month2=1;
    }else{
        $year2=$year1;
        $month2=$month1+1;
    }
    $m2_last=date('t',strtotime("$year2-$month2"));
    $result='[';
    $result.="['Day', '".date('M Y',strtotime("$year1-$month1"))."', '".date('M Y',strtotime("$year2-$month2"))."'],\n";
    for($i=1,$stop=31; $i<=$stop; ++$i){
        $result.="['".str_pad($i,2,0,STR_PAD_LEFT).".', ";  // pad single digit days with a leading zero, add trailing dot
        $result.="'".($i<=$m1_last ? getOrdersByDay($i,$month1,$year1) : getOrdersByDay(0,0,0))."', ";  // conditionally parameters
        $result.="'".($i<=$m2_last ? getOrdersByDay($i,$month2,$year2) : getOrdersByDay(0,0,0))."', ";  // conditionally parameters
        $result.=']'.($i<$stop ? ',' : ']')."\n";  // conditionally add comma to end of row
    }
    return $result;
}

echo buildPseudoArray(1,2017);  // 0, 0, 0 in first column
echo "\n---------------------\n";
echo buildPseudoArray('2',2017);  // 0, 0, 0 in second column
echo "\n---------------------\n";
echo buildPseudoArray(12,2017);  // incrementation into next year
```

Output of the 3 calls:

```
Result for 1-2017:
[['Day', 'Jan 2017', 'Feb 2017'],
['01.', '22', '9', ],
['02.', '30', '24', ],
['03.', '26', '5', ],
['04.', '46', '25', ],
['05.', '7', '24', ],
['06.', '17', '22', ],
['07.', '34', '27', ],
['08.', '0', '26', ],
['09.', '43', '38', ],
['10.', '27', '49', ],
['11.', '7', '22', ],
['12.', '14', '26', ],
['13.', '0', '30', ],
['14.', '45', '43', ],
['15.', '30', '45', ],
['16.', '34', '34', ],
['17.', '19', '30', ],
['18.', '34', '40', ],
['19.', '25', '39', ],
['20.', '1', '1', ],
['21.', '40', '49', ],
['22.', '26', '40', ],
['23.', '37', '44', ],
['24.', '16', '8', ],
['25.', '21', '3', ],
['26.', '47', '35', ],
['27.', '47', '25', ],
['28.', '1', '43', ],
['29.', '7', '30', ],
['30.', '8', '28', ],
['31.', '38', '13', ]]

---------------------
Result for 2-2017:
[['Day', 'Feb 2017', 'Mar 2017'],
['01.', '5', '48', ],
['02.', '43', '33', ],
['03.', '32', '13', ],
['04.', '30', '23', ],
['05.', '10', '41', ],
['06.', '3', '16', ],
['07.', '46', '23', ],
['08.', '3', '12', ],
['09.', '6', '23', ],
['10.', '48', '29', ],
['11.', '6', '49', ],
['12.', '14', '34', ],
['13.', '44', '2', ],
['14.', '17', '11', ],
['15.', '47', '44', ],
['16.', '35', '9', ],
['17.', '0', '26', ],
['18.', '26', '0', ],
['19.', '7', '5', ],
['20.', '0', '17', ],
['21.', '4', '9', ],
['22.', '43', '37', ],
['23.', '21', '28', ],
['24.', '22', '12', ],
['25.', '15', '50', ],
['26.', '16', '34', ],
['27.', '33', '21', ],
['28.', '2', '37', ],
['29.', '31', '41', ],
['30.', '50', '28', ],
['31.', '3', '34', ]]

---------------------
Result for 12-2017:
[['Day', 'Dec 2017', 'Jan 2018'],
['01.', '42', '48', ],
['02.', '17', '44', ],
['03.', '11', '26', ],
['04.', '5', '11', ],
['05.', '44', '1', ],
['06.', '37', '33', ],
['07.', '33', '32', ],
['08.', '43', '35', ],
['09.', '5', '35', ],
['10.', '27', '6', ],
['11.', '24', '0', ],
['12.', '35', '33', ],
['13.', '38', '4', ],
['14.', '11', '35', ],
['15.', '0', '18', ],
['16.', '3', '43', ],
['17.', '31', '20', ],
['18.', '12', '19', ],
['19.', '38', '34', ],
['20.', '38', '45', ],
['21.', '11', '32', ],
['22.', '12', '13', ],
['23.', '47', '38', ],
['24.', '37', '17', ],
['25.', '36', '44', ],
['26.', '47', '4', ],
['27.', '40', '48', ],
['28.', '5', '20', ],
['29.', '18', '4', ],
['30.', '15', '48', ],
['31.', '38', '19', ]]
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution, it does the trick. Still like the approach from @tbedner a bit more because it lets me use flexible years instead of a single one. Though modifying your solution would work for me as well!

Comment: Thank you for getting in touch and explaining the quality of your solution even more. I see why it's better than other answers but I'm missing the possibility to check several years. I'd like to use this not only with the specified dates, I need something scalable (means I'll have dates ins my array from 2015, 2016 as well, not only 2017).
In addition I updated my starting post with two tweaks in the output. Maybe you can help and adjust your code. Gonna check your solution and mark as accepted answer then! :)

Comment: I need this for Google Charts to illustrate order amounts of different dates. This is how it currently looks like: https://jsfiddle.net/96kktoj2/1/ (see the two `var data` arrays in JS section). I have a PHP function `getOrdersByDay($day_number, $month_number, $year_number)` which receives the database result which is a certain (order) amount. I'm using this PHP function in my JS-Code (not the best way, I know) and now I'm trying to perform this function for every date between two dates. In this fiddle I'm showing two examples how it looks like with PHP function and with real data.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend doing nothing even remotely like that. Dates and Times are not things you want to handle manually as they are far more complicated than they seem.

```
<?php
$period = new DatePeriod(
    new DateTime('2017-01-01'), // start
    new DateInterval('P1M'),    // interval of 1 month
    new DateTime('2018-01-01')  // end
);

foreach( $period as $date ) {
    printf("%s\n", $date->format('Y-m-d'));
}
```

Output:

```
2017-01-01
2017-02-01
2017-03-01
2017-04-01
2017-05-01
2017-06-01
2017-07-01
2017-08-01
2017-09-01
2017-10-01
2017-11-01
2017-12-01
```

http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php
http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateperiod.php
http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php
http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php

And just as a rule of thumb: If you ever find yourself manually defining huge, repetitive arrays like that you should probably take a step back and reexamine your approach.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I used a similar approach to create my array but struggled arranging / looping through the items as needed and get a result like:
'1, 10, 2017', '1, 11, 2017'
'2, 10, 2017', '2, 11, 2017'

and not:
'1, 10, 2017', '2, 10, 2017' 
and so on.

Answer (score 0):

I wholeheartedly agree with @Sammitch on this. If you must use this array, you can loop through your array and use strtotime to cast the entries in Unix time as such:

```
foreach($date_array as $key => $value) {
  $value = explode(",",$value);
  $value = trim($value[2])."-".trim($value[1])."-".trim($value[0]);
  $value = strtotime($value);
  $date_array[$key] = $value;
}
```

If you wanted to deal with the array as it is, here is something that will get you close to what you are looking for:

```
<?php
$date_array = array(
    0 => "1, 10, 2017",
    1 => "2, 10, 2017",
    2 => "3, 10, 2017",
    3 => "4, 10, 2017",
    4 => "5, 10, 2017",
    5 => "6, 10, 2017",
    6 => "7, 10, 2017",
    7 => "8, 10, 2017",
    8 => "9, 10, 2017",
    9 => "10, 10, 2017",
    10 => "11, 10, 2017",
    11 => "12, 10, 2017",
    12 => "13, 10, 2017",
    13 => "14, 10, 2017",
    14 => "15, 10, 2017",
    15 => "16, 10, 2017",
    16 => "17, 10, 2017",
    17 => "18, 10, 2017",
    18 => "19, 10, 2017",
    19 => "20, 10, 2017",
    20 => "21, 10, 2017",
    21 => "22, 10, 2017",
    22 => "23, 10, 2017",
    23 => "24, 10, 2017",
    24 => "25, 10, 2017",
    25 => "26, 10, 2017",
    26 => "27, 10, 2017",
    27 => "28, 10, 2017",
    28 => "29, 10, 2017",
    29 => "30, 10, 2017",
    30 => "31, 10, 2017",
    31 => "1, 11, 2017",
    32 => "2, 11, 2017",
    33 => "3, 11, 2017",
    34 => "4, 11, 2017",
    35 => "5, 11, 2017",
    36 => "6, 11, 2017",
    37 => "7, 11, 2017",
    38 => "8, 11, 2017",
    39 => "9, 11, 2017",
    40 => "10, 11, 2017",
    41 => "11, 11, 2017",
    42 => "12, 11, 2017",
    43 => "13, 11, 2017",
    44 => "14, 11, 2017",
    45 => "15, 11, 2017",
    46 => "16, 11, 2017",
    47 => "17, 11, 2017",
    48 => "18, 11, 2017",
    49 => "19, 11, 2017",
    50 => "20, 11, 2017",
    51 => "21, 11, 2017",
    52 => "22, 11, 2017",
    53 => "23, 11, 2017",
    54 => "24, 11, 2017",
    55 => "25, 11, 2017",
    56 => "26, 11, 2017",
    57 => "27, 11, 2017",
    58 => "28, 11, 2017",
    59 => "29, 11, 2017",
    60 => "30, 11, 2017"
);
for($i=1;$i<=31;$i++) {
  $line = "'".$i."', ";
  foreach($date_array as $key => $value) {
    $exp = explode(",",$value);
    if($exp[0] == $i) {
        $line .= "'".$value."', ";
    }
  }
  echo $line."<br />";
}

?>
```

Outputs:

'1', '1, 10, 2017', '1, 11, 2017',

'2', '2, 10, 2017', '2, 11, 2017',

...

'30', '30, 10, 2017', '30, 11, 2017',

'31', '31, 10, 2017',